# Tapestry5 Grid pagination not working in a Tapestry Loop

Tags: tapestry

Currently we are working on a report generation. We are facing an issue with pagination using tapestry grid component.

For a given date search criteria  (1-Nov-2010 to 2-Nov-2010). We are using a tapestry “Loop” component to 
iterate over the date range list,  which internally contains the list of transactions per day that is being 
displayed using the grid component.

Here the grid component is configured with “rowsPerPage=5” for the pagination.

• Assume for 1-Nov-2010, there are 11 rows, i.e., displays  [1, 2 , 3] pagination links. Here the pagination works as expected.

• For 2-Nov-2010, there are 21 rows, i.e., displays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] pagination links. But here on click of pagination link 4 and 5, it doesn’t list out the next set of rows.

In the initial investigation we observed that first grid pagination always takes the precedence over the other grids pagination.

Would like to know, if there any other configuration available to resolve this issue or is there any any other approach/solution 
is there to overcome this problem.

```html
<t:loop source="reports" value="report" encoder="reportEncoder">
    <t:grid source="report.reportObjects" row="reportObject" lean="true" inPlace="false" rowsPerPage="5" pagerPosition="bottom" class="decora" include="name", "age", "country", "city">
        <t:parameter name="nameCell">${name}</t:parameter>
        <t:parameter name="countryCell">${country}</t:parameter>
        <t:parameter name="cityCell">${city}</t:parameter>
    </t:grid>
</t:loop>
```

Comment: you might get more help if you post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: How works your `getReports()` getter for the `loop`? Do you take into account the page? Do you use the `onActivate()` and `onPassivate()` methods? The Java part would be a + to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes bbcooper. The iteration is for the same data but for different dates. But, from below example; when we click on the 3rd pagination link of second set of grid data; the result doesn't appears as expected. Because, the first set of grid data has only 2 pagination links.

### Day1

### NAME  COUNTRY  CITY

### abc    India   Nagpur

[1][2] (These are pagination links)

### Day2

### NAME  COUNTRY  CITY

### xyz   India   Mumbai

[1][2][3] (These are pagination links)